# Curve selection lemma for subanalytic sets

Tags: differential-geometry, logic

Curve selection lemma: Let $E\subset M$ be a subanalytic set. If $a\in \overline{E \setminus \{a\}}$, then there is an analytic function $\gamma : (−1, 1) \to M$ such that $\gamma(0) = a$ and $\gamma((0, 1)) \subset E$. Moreover, $\gamma$ is a homeomorphism on to its image $\gamma([0,1))$ which is a semi-analytic arc of class $C^1$.

The Curve selection lemma is true for bounded subanalytic sets because the latter form an o-minimal structure.

How can I show that the lemma remains true for all subanalytic sets?

Comment: Take the intersection of your subanalytic set with a bounded subanalytic ball around $a$.

Comment: Thank you very much  KReiser for your reply.

A Euclidean ball is a semi-analytic and therefore sub-analytic set, Furthermore the sub-analyticity is stable by finite intersection

I run to rectify